# GWT tutorial body padding

Tags: css, gwt, padding, document-body

GWT tutorial - StockWatcher.

I am overriding StockWatcher.css:

```
body {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

But no padding is applied, at least on the left, and the whole frame is flush to the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some panels in GWT use absolute positioning. Applying padding to widgets that are direct children of these panels won't work. In such situations you use, for example,

```
myLayoutPanel.setWidgetLeftRight(myWidget, 10, Unit.PX, 10, Unit.PX);
```

You can apply padding and margins to any widget whose parent does not use absolute positioning for its children (e.g. widgets inside FlowPanel or HTMLPanel).

Comment: But my change applied to the entire _body_ element. Why didn't that work?

Comment: If you don't add any placeholders in the host page, the RootLayoutPanel wraps the <body> element, i.e. occupies the entire browser window.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, but I am still not clear, how that fact prevents the body from having padding.

Comment: It does not. Your body element does have a padding. But RootLayoutPanel has absolute positioning, which means it is set not relative to its parent (body), but relative to the browser window. This has nothing to do with GWT per se: this is how CSS behaves in general.